# Kibana unable to connect to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, efk

I am having trouble getting Kibana to connect to elasticsearch. The error I get is below;

**plugin:elasticsearch@5.6.1    Request Timeout after 3000ms**

Elasticsearch has been deployed via kubernetes and runs as a service called *monitoring-es* with a cluster IP of *100.63.124.194*.

In my Kibana.yml file I have set the elasticsearch url as;

**elasticsearch.url: "http://100.63.124.194:9200**"

However I still get the same error. Is this the correct value or is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add manifest files (Elastic Search and Kibana) to your questions?

Comment: Does elasticsearch and kibana is in the same server? If yes try this: elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"

Comment: _Does elasticsearch and kibana is in the same server?_ unless kibana has spontaneously changed to a server-side app, that 100% won't work: the requests from kibana to ES come from _your browser_ not from inside kibana

Comment: Kibana and Elasticsearch run on 2 different servers.

Comment: Can you provide the logs for the elasticsearch container? Also, if you kubectl exec into elasticsearch container, can you curl localhost:9200?

Comment: Seem to be getting 'missing authentication token for rest request' error when trying to curl